# python defaultdict how can I check if a nested key exists or is [] without creating the key

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, defaultdict

There are 3 types of entries in a nested defaultdict `a` of structure `a=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`.

```
for i in a:
    print a[i]

defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'ldap_uidnumber': [['10002']], 'file': ['ABC', 'xyz']})
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'ldap_uidnumber': [], 'file': ['abcd']})
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'file': ['/home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub']})
```

1. How do I filter out the second one, with `ldap_uidnumber: []`?
2. How do I filter out the third one without the key `ldap_uidnumber` at all?

The code I tried:

```
for i in a:
    if a[i]["ldap_uidnumber"] and a[i]["ldap_uidnumber"] == []:
        print i
```

But that is not printing anything, but creating the key in the third value after this code, and looks like

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'ldap_uidnumber': [], 'file': ['/home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub']})
```

Comment: `if a[i].get("ldap_uidnumber"):`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking for membership using `in` doesn't create the key in a defaultdict. I would recommend that.

```
for i in a:
    if "ldap_uidnumber" in a[i] and      # shortcircuit here in your 3rd el
            not a[i]['ldap_uidnumber']:  # fail here in your 1st el
        # do something
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Use `defaultdict.get` which won't create keys on absence and will return `None` if the key doesn't exist or the value if present - `None` and `[]` are both `False` in a boolean context, so your code becomes:

```
for i in a:
    if a[i].get('ldap_uidnumber', []):
        # It's not missing or empty - do something...
```

Comment: You'll have to be careful here since you'll enter this block on both the 2nd and 3rd items. My assumption was that OP was looking for elements that had an `ldap_uidnumber` key that was blank, and was trying to exclude elements that didn't have that key.

Comment: Maybe using a default value for `get` method, would be good if you don't want to use `try-except` for handling the exception.

Comment: @Kasramvd `defaultdict.get` will return a default value of `None` unless otherwise told otherwise...

Comment: @JonClements Yep, but I meant something except None.

Comment: @Kasramvd what's wrong with `None` in this case - serves the role perfectly well

Comment: @JonClements he's trying to differentiate between non-existent keys and empty values, though `None` works here: If you're testing for a missing key: `if a[i].get('ldap_uidnumber') is None:` and if you're testing for an empty value: `if not a[i].get('ldap_uidnumber')`

Comment: @AdamSmith That's one of it's advantages, actually with using the default value we van send a message (not in this case!) or when we want to get the values based on a condition use it for refusing of defining `else`.

Comment: @JonClements Indeed, that it works in this case, and you've got my vote.I just gave a suggest.

Comment: @Kasramvd the problem you'll run into is when your default value happens to be equal to the value in the dictionary.

Comment: Okay - I've changed to be a default of an empty list - that way - whether it does or doesn't exist (an empty list is always a no) - so this more closely mimics @AdamSmith's answer in terms of logic... (if a key had a `None` value for instance - using `None` as a default would be slightly different)